# Oracle SQL Developer ver. 4.0.3.16 (TRIMSPOOL not supported)

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried using the command 'SET TRIMSPOOL ON' to output a query to a text file without trailing spaces, but, the command was just skipped.

Script output says:

```
SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set TRIMSPOOL ON
```

Do I need to update anything to make this command work?
My SQL Developer version is 4.0.3.16.

Comment: SQL Developer only supports a subset of the SQL*Plus commands.  If you need to use SQL*Plus commands that SQL Developer doesn't support, is there a reason that you wouldn't just use SQL*Plus?

Comment: Not all SQL*Plus commands are supported by SQL Developer. The links in my answer will redirect you to the list of supported commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **SQL Developer**, then there is no reason that you don't have **'SQL*Plus'***. It shouldn't be difficult to execute a script in 'SQLPlus'. **Not all 'SQL*Plus' commands are supported by SQL Developer.** And it depends on the version. Newer versions have more supported commands, but few are also deprecated.

A quick search for SQL Developer product and `SQL*Plus` support directed to this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sql-worksheet-commands-097146.html. All the supported SQL*Plus Commands are listed down.

That is about version 3.0 Since you are on 4.0, you could search for the SQL*Plus supported commands in SQL Developer 4.0 Follow this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index-097090.html